# How to fix hover problem on button with font awesome icon?

Tags: css, wordpress

When i click this button icons color cant change to blue but text color changed how can i solve this problem?

[Button without hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy2he.jpg)

[Button after hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQims.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is your problem, can you elaborate on it? Could you also provide us with a minimal working example where we can recreate your problem?

Comment: U must share your code or link to check the detail

Comment: <a class="btn-hover live-chat-btn" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-dots live-chat-icon"></i>Live Chat</a>

Comment: This is the code

Comment: .live-chat-btn:hover i{color:blue;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is two ways to do that:

1. You can set text-shadow like this: `.live-chat-btn { text-shadow:1px blue; }`
2. Or You can set the hover color: `.live-chat-btn:hover i { color: blue; }`

Choose which one is the best way.